# How to get paired devices list through bluetooth in swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth

I am working on a sample project to get list of paired  devices (iPhone and Andriod) through Bluetooth.below code is working find for me.but didDiscover method not being called. what is wrong with my code.any help will be appricated

Code :

```
transferServiceUUID = (CBUUID (string:"180D"))

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        guard central.state  == .poweredOn else {
            return
        }
        scanDevice()
    }

    func scanDevice() {

        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(
            withServices: [transferServiceUUID!], options: [
                CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : NSNumber(value: true as Bool)
            ]
        )

      }

    func didReadPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: NSNumber) {
        let name = peripheral.name

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        print("Discovered \(peripheral.name) at \(RSSI)")
       // if discoveredPeripheral != peripheral {
            discoveredPeripheral = [peripheral]
            print("Connecting to peripheral \(peripheral)")
            centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
       // }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Failed to connect to \(peripheral). (\(error!.localizedDescription))")

    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

        centralManager?.stopScan()
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices([transferServiceUUID!])
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate for centralManager ?

Comment: centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

Comment: "to get list of paired devices": No, you'll discover peripheral that are advertising. Try removing the `transferServiceUUID` in ` withServices: [transferServiceUUID!]`.

Comment: @Larem transferServiceUUID to be replaced by nil?